# Why is magento generating duplicate rewrites in the core_url_rewrite table?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I can give a very specific example.  BEFORE INDEXING:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE target_path = 'catalog/category/view/id/4';
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| url_rewrite_id | store_id | category_id | product_id | id_path      | request_path | target_path                | is_system | options | description |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|           1508 |        1 |           4 |       NULL | category/4_1 | food.html    | catalog/category/view/id/4 |         1 |         |             |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

AFTER INDEXING:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE target_path = 'catalog/category/view/id/4';
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| url_rewrite_id | store_id | category_id | product_id | id_path      | request_path | target_path                | is_system | options | description |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|           1508 |        1 |           4 |       NULL | category/4_1 | food.html    | catalog/category/view/id/4 |         1 |         |             |
|           8512 |        1 |           4 |       NULL | category/4   | food-1.html  | catalog/category/view/id/4 |         1 |         | NULL        |
+----------------+----------+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So my question is, why on earth would Magento create a duplicate rewrite?  Is this a bug?

Any insight would be very appreciated.  Thanks!

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose this was a bug in Magento 1.4.  Upgrading to 1.6 resolved the issue.

Comment: Just kidding.  It's happening again.